# How to copy data from one spreadsheet to another on edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to program a spreadsheet so that whenever I add a new entry to it, it copies the data from that cell into another spreadsheet. Here's my code (that doesn't seem to work):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("*************");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":G"+(last_row+1));
  e.range.copyTo(target_range);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of triggers in Apps Scripts - simple triggers and installable triggers.
onEdit() is an example of a simple trigger (the name is implicit). And there are limits to what you can do inside a simple trigger. And that includes opening another spreadsheet.

So, coming to the solution. 
Rename your function to something else, say onEdit1() . And set up an installable trigger manually and set it to run each time the spreadsheet is edited. 
Hint: Use Resources --> Current project's triggers from the script editor

Comment: Is there any way to access the current cell that is being in onEdit1()?

Comment: Fixed it :) I just got the last row of the spreadsheet rather than using an event object. Thanks!